# How to get/view/show current value of a setting in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a simple way of finding out the current value of a specified Vim setting? If I want to know the current value of, say `tabstop`, I can run:

```
:set tabstop
```

without passing an argument, and Vim will tell me the current value. This is fine for many settings, but it is no good for those that are either true or false. For example, if I want to find out the current value of `expandtab`, running:

```
:set expandtab
```

will actually enable `expandtab`. I just want to find out if it is enabled or not.

This sort of does what I want:

```
:echo &l:expandtab
```

but it seems quite verbose. Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 516, accepted):

Add a `?` mark after the setting name and it will show the value, e.g.,

```
:set expandtab?
```

Comment: Note that the `set <...>?` syntax will work for "settings" that are _options_, but not for "settings" that are _variables_. So for example, to find out what the current syntax highlighting mode is (encoded in a variable, not an option), you need to do `echo b:current_syntax`.

Comment: If you want to also see _where_ the option was set from, use `verbose`. For this example, `:verbose set expandtab`.

Comment: How do see the current value of settings such as `behave`? I have tried `behave?` and `set behave?`. Unfortunately, they do not work.

Comment: @mkobit I had to use `:verbose set expandtab?` for it to work

Comment: Useful answer. But I wish `:get` worked...

Answer (score 60):

Alternatively, the `&` symbol can be used to mean "option" - e.g.

```
let x = &expandtab
echo &expandtab
```

Comment: Is there also an option to get the value of a list element? (e.g. space of listchars)

Comment: I believe listchars is an ordinary string, not a List, though I guess you could do something like `split(&listchars, ',')`

Answer (score 29):

If you don't remember what setting you want to check, you can view all settings:

```
:set all
```

or show each setting, one setting per line:

```
:set! all
```

Answer (score 6):

There are also additional vim settings that can be displayed as well, such as:

`:highlight`

For the full list, see:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_the_current_Vim_environment

Edit: There is some misunderstanding of my answer. This does not work for any command. But it does work for all the commands listed in the URL above.

Comment: This does not work. I wanted to check whether `autowrite` is on. `:set autowrite?` does the job.

Comment: @Atcold: this does work for *some* settings, for which only this type of query will work.

Comment: @gmarmstrong: I see the answer have been edited with such remark.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Neovim, use Lua:

`:lua print(vim.o.<option>)`

For example:

```
:lua print(vim.o.foldmethod)
expr
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
:verbose set tabstop? expandtab?
```

It will also tell you from which config file are the settings coming.