# Can you query what a variable/setting in vim is set to?

Tags: vim

For example, in vim, if I want to know if autoread is set or not, is there a command I can run to tell me?  Or to know what my tabstop is set to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current value of a setting in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078271/get-current-value-of-a-setting-in-vim)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, `:set autoread?` will give you the current value of autoread. Generally, `set foo?` will give you the value of option `foo`.

`:set` will display all options that are different from default.

Answer (score 8):

`:verbose set autoread?` will tell you what set autoread and its value.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do, for example,

```
echo &ft
```

The `&` refers to the contents of the variable. I find this useful in scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can view settings in vim with this command

```
:set all
```