# Displaying Vim variables

Tags: vim, macvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get current value of a setting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078271/get-current-value-of-a-setting-in-vim)

I know that you can use `:set` to change Vim settings and that you can set up a configuration file `~/.vimrc` but I'm running into some issues getting this to work with MacVim and I want to be able to display what a Vim environment variable is.

Is there a command like `:show tw` or something like this that will do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please close instead of answering duplicates, people. Above is one, [here is another one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5314147/557306).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
:set tw?
```

or if you want to know where it is set as well

```
:verbose set tw?
```

For even more setting fun

```
:options
```

Comment: BTY, this is showing *options* not *variables*. For variables the command is  `echo VAR`.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the accepted answer you may also use `:echo &tw`.

This has the advantage that you can't accidentally set a boolean option by forgetting to add the `?`.  The disadvantage is that you cannot use this method with `verbose`.

Comment: I upvoted, but Avoid answering duplicates Randy, close it instead.

Comment: @sidyll - Apparently I've seen one of these in the past as I have voted for one of the answers, however I did not remember it.  If there is some secret way of duplicates popping out at me without me searching every single question I decide to answer, I'm not seeing it.  If you'd rather me leave questions unanswered that I know an answer to because someone somewhere may have asked a similar question before that I am totally unaware of I can start doing that instead.  This answer was clearly posted at least an hour before you marked it a duplicate and now that you have, I have voted to close.

Comment: I see, no worries. Maybe the system will be improved enough in the future to find duplicates better; on the other hand, it's asker's responsibility to search thoughtfully. And thanks for supporting my vote :-)