# GVIM: How to add toolbar icon to toggle between 'ignorecase' and 'noignorecase'?

Tags: vim, vi

How can I create a new toolbar icon in GVIM (7.4 on Windows) that can toggle between case-insensitive/case-sensitive searching ?

I can do this manually by doing:

```
:set ignorecase
:set noignorecsae
```

But I use this so often it would be nice to have an (ideally a single on/off toggle) icon for this.

EDIT: Following one answer on here (with mods); I can add a drop-down ("Shortcuts") menu like this to do (nearly) what I want:

```
:amenu Shorcuts.ic :set ic<CR>
:amenu Shorcuts.noic :set noic<CR>
```

But trying to add to the toolbar menu (as per the suggested answer) like this:

```
:amenu ToolBar.Hello :echo "hello"<CR>
```

Has no effect on my toolbar - it remains looking like this screenshot:

[image: Toolbar Screenshot]

Additionally; I can get the current value of the setting (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078271/get-current-value-of-a-setting-in-vim)) by using &ignorecase, for example:

```
:echo &ignorecase
```

Which reports back '0' or '1' depending if it is set or not.
I guess I can somehow use that to 'toggle' an icon in the toolbar ?

[Get current value of a setting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078271/get-current-value-of-a-setting-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

Toolbars in Vim are just like any menu with name `ToolBar`.  You can can add an item by something like:

```
:amenu ToolBar.Hello :echo "hello"<CR>
```

For more info use

```
:help gui-toolbar
```